# Java: How to iterate two variables inside nested for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop

UPDATE: SOLVED!!!  Answer below

```
    System.out.println("Remainders:"); 

    // BEGIN REMAINDER CHART CONTENTS 

    // Prints Denominator list 
        System.out.print("\tn"); 
    for (int denom = 1; denom <= max_denom; denom++) {
        System.out.print("\tn%" + denom);
    }
    System.out.println();


    // prints numerator lines along with remainders 
    for (int numer = 1; numer <= max_numer; numer++) {
      System.out.print(numer);
      for (int denom = 1; denom <= max_denom; denom++) { 
          System.out.print("\t" + numer%denom);
      }
    }
      System.out.println();
  } 
}
```

Hello!  I am having with the second part of this java program - wherein you use a nested for loop to iterate as many lines as are = to the numerator.  The idea is to create a chart of remainders as output, like so:

```
Remainders:
n   n%1 n%2 n%3 n%4 n%5 n%6
1   0   ?
2   0   ?
3   0   ?
4   0   ?
5   0   ?
```

Going to my prof's office hours today didn't seem to help me figure it out either.  Anybody want to point me in the right direction?  I've spent over 8 hours and I can't get my brain around what I'm doing wrong...

The output looks correct but is scrambled.

================ANSWER===================

Don't have enough rep to answer my own question, but here's the solution:

```
    // BEGIN REMAINDER CHART CONTENTS 

    // Prints Denominator list 
        System.out.print("\tn"); 
    for (int denom = 1; denom <= max_denom; denom++) {
        System.out.print("\tn%" + denom);
    }
    System.out.println();


    // prints numerator lines along with remainders 
    for (int numer = 1; numer <= max_numer; numer++) {
      System.out.print("\t" + numer);
      for (int denom = 1; denom <= max_denom; denom++) { 
          System.out.print("\t" + numer%denom);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  } 
}
```

outputs:

```
n   n%1 n%2 n%3 n%4 n%5 n%6
1   0   1   1   1   1   1
2   0   0   2   2   2   2
3   0   1   0   3   3   3
4   0   0   1   0   4   4
5   0   1   2   1   0   5
```

Beautiful -- thank you Njol so much, I was losing my mind trying to overthink that one!

Comment: Sorry, but where are you attempting to nest for loops ***anywhere*** in the code above? It's hard to help figure out what you're doing wrong if we don't see an attempt.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - updated to show proper attempt; uploaded wrong original by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to put one loop into the other, using a different loop variable:

```
// print header (n   n%1 n%2 etc.)
System.out.print("n");
for (int denom = 1; denom <= max_denom; denom++)
    System.out.print("\tn%"+denom);
System.out.println();

// print table
for (int numer = 1; numer <= max_numer; numer++) {
    System.out.print(numer);
    for (int denom = 1; denom <= max_denom; denom++) {
        System.out.print("\t" + numer%denom);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Note that I use `System.out.print` to print text on the one line, and use `System.out.println()` to end the line.

Comment: I see what you're illustrating, I guess I had a variation of this earlier but still ran into the problem of formatting output correctly:

Comment: Oh man now I get what I was doing wrong; thank you so much.  answer code to follow below.

Comment: `// Prints Denominator list 
        System.out.print("\tn"); 
    for (int denom = 1; denom <= max_denom; denom++) {
        System.out.print("\tn%" + denom);
    }
    System.out.println();
            
    
    // prints numerator lines along with remainders 
    for (int numer = 1; numer <= max_numer; numer++) {
      System.out.print("\t" + numer);
      for (int denom = 1; denom <= max_denom; denom++) { 
          System.out.print("\t" + numer%denom);
      }
      System.out.println();
     }
    }`